# Convert dataframe series to integer

Tags: python, pandas

These two lines of code print the output shown below.

```
variable = df1['Name'].str[11:14]
print(variable.head(2))
```

```
0   025
1   012
```

However, when I try to convert the string to an integer I get this error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>"

```
variable = df1['Name'].str[11:14]
variable = int(variable)
print(variable.head(2))
```

How do I convert this string to an integer?

Answer (score 0):

variable is not a string, but a Pandas series of strings.

The way I would do it is variable = variable.astype(int), but you have a few options...

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas) should help you out.